# Make black dot behind around div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spectrumjs

I implemented [Spectrum Color Picker](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). There is a slight change I want to make. The black dot that you can drag to select a color, the class name is `sp-dragger`. I want to edit the [source file](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js) so that when you drag the black dot all the way to the side, (top, right, bottom and left side,) anything from the border of the class name `sp-color` and on, should hide the black dot.

[image]

(Image is from Adobe Illustrator)

I think the way to do this would be to create a div, or use an existing div, and make the `z-index` higher than the black dot.

#### JSFiddle

[JavaScirpt Source](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js)

[CSS Source](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for this part in the css source:

```
.sp-color {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:20%;

   /* Then add this line */
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

So the content doesn't bleed outside its edge.

Comment: Thanks! That works! Can you explain how that worked?

Comment: If you inspect the html of the color picker you can see that the black dot is a child element of the color panel - which has the class sp-color. So CSS has a feature fit your situation perfectly, that is `overflow: hidden`, which hide all child content that extends outside an element's boundaries.

Comment: Got it! Genius solution!